# Rotating image in WPF not respecting screen size

Tags: c#, wpf, image-rotation

I am currently having trouble when rotating an image in WPF, using `RotateTransform` and `LayoutTransform`. When an image, that has a pixel height size greater than the monitors height and is rotated at 90º or 270º, the window size will be higher than the monitors screen resolution size.

Example screenshots:
[Application running with image at 90º](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8EfR.jpg)
[Application running with image at 0º](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkOkk.jpg)

I am using the code below (simplified), with *mainWindow.img* being a `System.Windows.Control.Image`:

```
static void Rotate(int degrees)
{
    var rt = new RotateTransform { Angle = degrees };
    mainWindow.img.LayoutTransform = rt;
}
```

It is for a a picture viewer project, the full source code is available at https://github.com/Ruben2776/PicView

I have tried shifting the Width and Height values of the image, but it produces an undesired result (skewed proportion).

The sizing calculation, for the image size, is made based on the user's screen height, using the following trimmed code:

```
int interfaceHeight = 90;
double maxWidth = Math.Min(MonitorInfo.Width, width);
double maxHeight = Math.Min((MonitorInfo.Height - interfaceHeight), height);
double AspectRatio = Math.Min((maxWidth / width), (maxHeight / height));
mainWindow.img.Width = (width * AspectRatio);
mainWindow.img.Height = (height * AspectRatio);
```

with `height` and `width` being the image's dimensions and `MonitorInfo` being a class that retrieves the current monitors resolution.

## Update

Below is the minimal code for a sample WPF app illustrating the issue:

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="RotateTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="Fill" Source="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/nk/wallhaven-nkrwz1.jpg"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace RotateTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int Degrees;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
            KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Key)
            {                
                case Key.Up:
                    Rotate(true);
                    break;
                case Key.Down:
                    Rotate(false);
                    break;

            }
        }

        private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int interfaceHeight = 90;
            double maxWidth = Math.Min(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, img.Source.Width);
            double maxHeight = Math.Min(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - interfaceHeight, img.Source.Height);
            double AspectRatio = Math.Min((maxWidth / img.Source.Width), (maxHeight / img.Source.Height));
            img.Width = (img.Source.Width * AspectRatio);
            img.Height = (img.Source.Height * AspectRatio);
        }

        void Rotate(int degrees)
        {
            var rt = new RotateTransform { Angle = Degrees = degrees };
            img.LayoutTransform = rt;
        }

        void Rotate(bool right)
        {
            switch (Degrees)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (right)
                    {
                        Rotate(270);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Rotate(90);
                    }

                    break;

                case 90:
                    if (right)
                    {
                        Rotate(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Rotate(180);
                    }

                    break;

                case 180:
                    if (right)
                    {
                        Rotate(90);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Rotate(270);
                    }

                    break;

                case 270:
                    if (right)
                    {
                        Rotate(180);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Rotate(0);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are only calculating your scaling ratios based on the the image's size *when it's not rotated*. Once you rotate the image, `img.ActualHeight` effectively becomes its width and `img.ActualWidth` effectively becomes its height, and your calculation from when the image was un-rotated is no longer correct.

Here are the changes and additions I made to your code:

```
private double normalRatio;
private double rotatedRatio;

private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double interfaceHeight = this.ActualHeight - img.ActualHeight;

    normalRatio = Math.Min(SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width / img.Source.Width, (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - interfaceHeight) / img.Source.Height);
    rotatedRatio = Math.Min(SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width / img.Source.Height, (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - interfaceHeight) / img.Source.Width);

    ScaleImage();
}

private void ScaleImage()
{
    double ratio = Degrees == 0 || Degrees == 180 ? normalRatio : rotatedRatio;
    img.Width = (img.Source.Width * ratio);
    img.Height = (img.Source.Height * ratio);
}

void Rotate(bool right)
{
    if (right)
    {
        Degrees -= 90;
        if (Degrees < 0) { Degrees += 360; }
    }
    else
    {
        Degrees += 90;
        if (Degrees >= 360) { Degrees -= 360; }
    }

    ScaleImage();
    Rotate(Degrees);
}

//I left the other methods, including Rotate(int degrees), the same as in your question
```

Here's an explanation of what I changed:

- `interfaceHeight` is calculated by subtracting the height of the image from the height of the window, the difference being the aggrigate size of everything else.
- Instead of using `MonitorInfo`, I'm using [`SystemParameters.WorkArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea), because it takes into account the size and placement of the Windows taskbar.
- I calculate *two* scale ratios: `normalRatio`, for when the image is not rotated or is vertically flipped (180°), and `rotatedRatio`, for when the image is rotated 90° in either direction. I calculate the later by swapping `img.Source.Height` and `img.Source.Width`.
- I added a `ScaleImage()` method to do the actual image scaling based on the intended rotation, so I can call it from two different places.
- I simplified `Rotate(bool right)` to calculate the new angle using math, instead of listing out each possible rotation.

The above results in an image that is always as big as possible for the screen while maintaining the original aspect ratio. It will grow and shrink as it's rotated to fit the screen. If you want the image to stay a constant size instead, just use `Math.Min(normalRatio, rotatedRatio)`.

Note that the above only works if you call `Rotate(bool right)`, *not* if you call `Rotate(int degrees)` directly. This is because the logic of using two ratios only works because there are only two possible sizes for the image (portrait and landscape), which is only the case if you restrict the rotation to increments of 90°. If you want to set the angle to something else, like 20°, the math to calculate the image's effective size becomes a bit more complicated and you would need to start calculating it dynamically based on the angle.